# OnStudentIDChanged no definition

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-properties

In my main window named (MainWindow by mistake) I have a method for getting a value once it has been triggered, this works for my usercontrols but for some reason when I attempt this on my MainWindow there are no definitions for OnStudentIDChanged.

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty StudentIDProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("StudentID", typeof(String), typeof(LoginWindow), new PropertyMetadata(OnStudentIDChanged));

    public string StudentID
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(StudentIDProperty); }
        set { SetValue(StudentIDProperty, value); }
    }

    static void OnStudentIDChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        (d as LoginWindow).OnStudentIDChanged(e); // OnStudentIDChanged no definition?
    }
```

Comment: And your MainWindow has a definition for OnStudentIDChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) ???

Comment: what do you want to do when StudentID property changes?

Comment: Please check for  LoginWindow/MainWindow typos.

Comment: Yeah it was a typo... hmm cant delete the question because it has answers.

Comment: At least make sure the question-text is accurate so that the answers make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps your intention was to cast `d` to `MainWindow` instead of `LoginWindow`?

```
static void OnStudentIDChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    (d as MainWindow).OnStudentIDChanged(e); 
}
```

but that is still wrong because it's an infinite recursion (guessing from your previous post)...

Comment: I think that was a typo.

Answer (score 0):

I'm making some assumptions here but i'm guessing that `static void OnStudentIDChanged` is located in MainWindow, right?

The problem is that you cannot call static methods of a type using an instance of that type. For example

```
public class MyClass
{
   public static void SomeMethod();
}

var instance = new MyClass();
(instance as MyClass).SomeMethod() //THIS WILL NOT WORK
```

Again, this is assuming I'm understanding your scenario correctly.

Is **d** always a **LoginWindow** in the following line?

```
(d as LoginWindow).OnStudentIDChanged(e);
```